# How to use the same alert with different content (?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js, lodash

Quick question

I am using angular strap to show some alerts, every single alert is in a different variable, but I want to avoid doing that, some one tell me to use `_.extend` from lodash, but how should I use it in this special case ?

```
var loaderAlert1 = $alert({
    animation: 'fx-bounce-right',
    content: 'Loading content, please wait...',
    container: '.alerts-container',
    type: 'info',
    show: true
  }),
  loaderAlert2 = $alert({
    animation: 'fx-bounce-right',
    content: 'Adding Line to BetSlip',
    container: '.alerts-container',
    type: 'info',
    show: false
  }),
  loaderAlert3 = $alert({
    animation: 'fx-bounce-right',
    content: 'Loading your messages, please wait...',
    container: '.alerts-container',
    type: 'info',
    show: false
  });
```

as you see, is almost the same but in some cases the show attr is set to true or false, and the `content:` also changes.

The way I am calling this alerts: `loaderAlert1.show()` or `loaderAlert1.hide()` and so on...

so I want to do something like

```
var loaderAlert = $alert({
    animation: 'fx-bounce-right',
    content: 'Loading content, please wait...',
    container: '.alerts-container',
    type: 'info',
    show: true
  });

loaderAlert = {content: 'loading something else'};

loaderAlert = {content: 'loading something GREAT'};

loaderAlert = {content: 'loading only ROCK N ROLL'};
```

where I declare only one variable, and then once I call the variable, I can change `content:`... but I don't know how `_.extend`, [here is the function I mentioned](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#assign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
   function customAlert( content ) {
         var loaderAlert = $alert({
            animation: 'fx-bounce-right',
            content: content,
            container: '.alerts-container',
             type: 'info',
            show: true
          });

         return loaderAlert;
    }
```

Еdit:

```
var content = 'loading something else', // choose one of the three choices here
     loaderAlert = customAlert(content);
```

Comment: how should I use it once I decide to call it ?

Comment: any idea of how to hide it ?

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer You mean, changing the show property too?

Comment: I mean, before I was doing ```loaderAlert.hide()``` so the alert disappear. Something like that

Comment: @NietzscheProgrammer I do not see why you would not be able to do so now too.

Answer (score 1):

```
var loaderAlert = $alert({
    animation: 'fx-bounce-right',
    container: '.alerts-container',
    type: 'info',
    show: true
  });

loaderAlert = _.extend({content: 'loading something else'}, loaderAlert);
```

Comment: hide? change the show property to false and use something like `ng-show="loaderAlert.show"`

Comment: before I was doing ```loaderAlert.hide()```, that's what I meant.

Comment: anyways your solution is not working, it is not showing the alert with content, it is just a white alert with no letters

Answer (score 1):

`_.extend` will help you, but re-using an object across calls to `$alert`is probably a bad idea - you may find that you need to refer back to a given `content` value later.

If you provide a new object as the first parameter to `_.extend`, you can clone the base parameters for each alert:

```
var base = {
    animation: 'fx-bounce-right',
    content: 'Loading content, please wait...',
    container: '.alerts-container',
    type: 'info',
    show: true
  }

$alert(_.extend({}, base, { content: 'first alert' }));
$alert(_.extend({}, base, { content: 'second alert' }));
$alert(_.extend({}, base, { content: 'third alert' }));
```

Comment: great, how do I hide it ?